# Downloading File in Android

Tags: android, file, url, download

I am using the following code  to Download File in Android:

```
public class FileDownloadActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FileDownloadActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downlaoding File...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        // execute this when the downloader must be fired
        DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
        downloadFile.execute("http://code.google.com/android/goodies/wallpaper/android-wallpaper5_1024x768.jpg");   
    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            try {
                Log.i("","In doin bggggggggggggg");
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/sample.jpg");
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override  
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just showing me 0% progress for the past half an hour.

I hav even added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

in manifest 
and even Internet is working fine in my phone.

Please help.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `onProgressUpdate` and run in debug mode, does it stop at your breakpoint?

Comment: include your logcat...how does it fail? What's going wrong?

Comment: If you're going to catch `Exception` and not do anything with it, you should at least log it: `Log.error("FileDownload", e)`.

Comment: Thanks Nick.. err is resolved.. was getting FileNotFound Exception..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that"connection.getContentLength()" is unreliable over HTTP and returns 0 so you're probably getting a divide by zero Exception. And since you don't log the exception you don't see anything in Logcat and no progress..

Answer (score 0):

If your minimum SDK Level is 9, have a look at [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

the lib will be help you

https://github.com/AriaLyy/Aria

## download file only one code

```
Aria.download(this)
    .load(DOWNLOAD_URL)
    .setDownloadPath(DOWNLOAD_PATH) //file save path
    .add();
```

## get download state

```
@Download.onPre(DOWNLOAD_URL)
  protected void onPre(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskStart
  void taskStart(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskRunning
  protected void running(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskResume
  void taskResume(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskStop
  void taskStop(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskCancel
  void taskCancel(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskFail
  void taskFail(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onTaskComplete
  void taskComplete(DownloadTask task) {}

  @Download.onNoSupportBreakPoint
  public void onNoSupportBreakPoint(DownloadTask task) {}
```