# Proxy can not be resolved

Tags: android, proxy, httpurlconnection

I used the same code with only little changes as follows from here :
[Downloading File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102812/downloading-file-in-android)

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                    "Myproxy", 8080));   
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);  
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection(proxy);  
                 uc.connect();  
 int fileLength = uc.getContentLength();
```

I am getting following exception for this:
    04-12 09:31:42.401: WARN/System.err(5181): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: Myproxy:8080
    04-12 09:31:42.405: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1057)
    04-12 09:31:42.405: WARN/System.err(5181):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:62)
     04-12 09:31:42.405: WARN/System.err(5181):     at      org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
    04-12 09:31:42.405: WARN/System.err(5181):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
    04-12 09:31:42.409: WARN/System.err(5181):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:884)
    04-12 09:31:42.409: WARN/System.err(5181):     at com.test.filedownload.FileDownloadActivity$DownloadFile.doInBackground(FileDownloadActivity.java:99)
    04-12 09:31:42.413: WARN/System.err(5181):     at com.test.filedownload.FileDownloadActivity$DownloadFile.doInBackground(FileDownloadActivity.java:1)
    04-12 09:31:42.416: WARN/System.err(5181):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    04-12 09:31:42.420: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    04-12 09:31:42.420: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    04-12 09:31:42.420: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    04-12 09:31:42.424: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    04-12 09:31:42.424: WARN/System.err(5181):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Please help to resolve the same.

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in Android versions 2.2 that they do not support Proxy
 But some phones like LG P500 works with OPera as the brwoser.
 There is a great detail about this on

```
http://android-proxy.blogspot.com/
```

But you can really achive this using proxoid, it is an HTTP proxy for Android.

```
code.google.com/p/proxoid/
```

More information can be had from this site.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: Myproxy:8080

This says that there is no host named Myproxy in the network. Obtain the proxy name and port and use them in code.

Comment: i am sure that there is that proxy and port number as i am able to do the same in java.

Comment: The emulator might not be able to translate the name into an ip address. Try one of the following:
1. Obtain IP of the proxy and use it in place of name.
2. In place of configuring proxy in code, Configure the emulator to use a proxy(Use IP to be safe in place of name). Instructions: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#proxy